# Convert sccm to tor*l/s

Tags: dimensional-analysis

I have found conversion tables for sccm to various units, but I am confused about how one is converting a volume/time unit (1 sccm = cm^3/min) to a volume*pressure/time i.e., torr l/s.
Can someone help me understand what assumptions are being made to make this conversion?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interpretation of a flow rate measured in torr L/s is that if you had a 1 L container of gas, the pressure in it is dropping by 1 torr per second from an outward leak (alternatively, for an initially evacuated container and an inward leak, the pressure is rising by the same rate). See [this industry FAQ item](https://www.sonotecusa.com/products/preventive-maintenance/expertise/resources/faq/faq-l5/) or page 5 of [this industry primer](https://www.leyboldproducts.com/media/pdf/90/c7/87/Fundamentals_of_Leak_Detection_EN.pdf), for example.

Comment: thanks. I found the answer in one of the links you provided. The answer being, by 1 cm3/min one really is saying (cm3 * 1 atm) / min.